# Ajax AutocompleteExtender not fetching data from SQL Server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I'm trying to create a search field with autocomplete based on the database using Ajax AutoCompleteExtender, and when I run the code it fetch nothing but a weird letters shows in the search list.

In aspx.cs file:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod]
    public static List<string> SearchEmails(string prefixText, int count)
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection())
        {
            conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["iasConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "select email from Emails where email like @email + '%'";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", prefixText);
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                conn.Open();
                List<string> emails = new List<string>();
                using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (sdr.Read())
                    {
                        emails.Add(sdr["email"].ToString());
                    }
                }
                conn.Close();

                return emails;
            }
        }
    }
```

In aspx file(HTML):

```
<head runat="server">
    <title>Emails</title>
     
  
</head>
<body>
   <form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
   <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:TextBox ID="EmailSearch" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<ajax:AutoCompleteExtender ID="AutoCompleteExtender1" runat="server" ServiceMethod="SearchEmails"
    MinimumPrefixLength="2" CompletionInterval="100" EnableCaching="false" CompletionSetCount="10"
    TargetControlID="EmailSearch" FirstRowSelected="false">
</ajax:AutoCompleteExtender>
   
</div>
</form>
</body>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/akSey.png)

Answer (score 0):

Hum, that should work. This works for me:

It might be that you have to JUST tag the function as a webmethod.

This works for me:

```
   [WebMethod]
    public static List<string> SearchHotels(string prefixText, int count)
    {            
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("",conn))
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT HotelName from tblHotels where HotelName like @h + '%' " +
                   "ORDER BY HotelName";

                cmd.Parameters.Add("@h", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = prefixText;
                conn.Open();
                DataTable rstData = new DataTable();
                rstData.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());

                List<string> Hotels = new List<string>();
                foreach (DataRow OneRow in rstData.Rows)
                    Hotels.Add(OneRow["HotelName"].ToString());

                return Hotels;
            }
        }
    }
```

I strong typed the parameter, but try your code as WebMethod, and see if that works.

My Markup:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Width="255px"></asp:TextBox>

<ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender ID="TextBox1_AutoCompleteExtender" 
    runat="server" BehaviorID="TextBox1_AutoCompleteExtender" 
    DelimiterCharacters=""  TargetControlID="TextBox1" MinimumPrefixLength="1" 
    ServiceMethod="SearchHotels" CompletionInterval="500" EnableCaching="False">
</ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender>
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately I got the same problem, is there a configuration I should do before using Ajax Toolkit?